# Setting Date format in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am retrieving date values from dataset(_dsst) and populating them in dropdown list(drpStartYear).

Since I am storing date as datetime datatype, I am getting date values as **mm-dd-yyyy 00:00:00** , where **00:00:00** is the time. But I need to get date only in **dd-mm-yyyy** format in dropdown list. I tried using **datatextformatstring**, but it is not working.

Below is the code:

```
 drpStartYear.DataSource = _dstt.Tables["tbSettings"].DefaultView;    
 drpStartYear.DataValueField = "StartDate";    

 drpStartYear.DataTextFormatString = "{0:d}";   
 drpStartYear.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you set DataTextField as well ?

Comment: drpStartYear.DataSource =_dstt.Tables["tbSettings"].DefaultView;       
   drpStartYear.DataValueField = "StartDate";     

     drpStartYear.DataTextFormatString = "{0:d}";       
     drpStartYear.DataBind();

Comment: I also want to conclude, datatextformatstring doesnot work if datavaluefield is used instead of datatextfield

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
drpStartYear.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
```

EDIT:  Add this:

```
drpStartYear.DataTextField = "StartDate";
```

Comment: I dont need time @Garath, but still above is not working, I know i need to use  format as "{0:d}" , but how to set it in drop down list, that is giving me headache

Answer (score 3):

You have to set DataTextField as well -

```
  drpStartYear.DataValueField = "StartDate";

  drpStartYear.DataTextField = "StartDate";
  drpStartYear.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
  drpStartYear.DataBind();
```

Comment: this is the answer, but I can mark only one as answer , sadly

Answer (score 2):

```
drpStartYear.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
drpStartYear.DataTextField = "StartDate";
```

or you can set this in your mark-up as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList
id="drpStartYear"
runat="server"
DataTextField = "StartDate"
DataTextFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"/>
```

Comment: It is not working, although "{0:d}" worked perfectly for setting date format of columns in GridView, where I  used DataFormatString="{0:d}" , but how to do same in case of dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, I was using DataValueField,     which didnot allow me to use DataTextFormatString, So When I changed it to DataTextField, I got intended results :)

```
 drpStartYear.DataSource = _dstt.Tables["tbSettings"].DefaultView;    
 drpStartYear.DataTextField = "StartDate";  

 drpStartYear.DataTextFormatString = "{0:d}";   
 drpStartYear.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
drpStartYear.DataTextFormatString = "0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: OP doesn't require time part

Comment: @Anuj DataTextFormatString  doesnot work on using datavaluefield, that was the problem, when i used datatextfield, it solved my problem