# Want to remove time from date in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is my code by which i bind dropdownlist data from sql..i want to
 remove the time part from date...

```
string query = "select distinct PaperStartDate from HMDPaperManage ";
ddlPaperDate.DataSource = clsSqlFunctions.GetSelectedData(query);

ddlPaperDate.DataTextField = "PaperStartDate";
ddlPaperDate.DataBind();
```

---

```
23/04/2014 00:00:00:00
```

and i want

```
23/04/2014
```

Comment: Did you try to format the string representation of your date?

Comment: Checkout this example and modify as required http://stackoverflow.com/a/17146281/1370442

Comment: You should trim it in DB query, like  `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),client_exp_date, 111)` and can check this for other formats http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "DataTextFormatString to "d" i.e.

```
ddlPaperDate.DataTextFormatString = "d";
```

This gives the added benefit that you can change up how the date is formatted based on standard string.format() conversions.

For more info, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The syntax is not correct. It should be ddlPaperDate.DataTextFormatString = "{0:d}" . Just putting "d" caused my dropdown textfield to populated with a "d".

Answer (score 2):

```
string query = "select distinct DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PaperStartDate), 0) from HMDPaperManage ";
```

try this solution

`DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, PaperStartDate), 0)` should take only date part

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the DropDownList values asbelow:

```
for(int i=0;i<ddlPaperDate.Items.Count;i++)
{
  ddlPaperDate.Items[i]=DateTime.ParseExact(ddlPaperDate.Items[i].Text,
      "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just update your Query like

```
string query = "select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),PaperStartDate,103) as 'PaperStartDate' from HMDPaperManage ";
ddlPaperDate.DataSource = clsSqlFunctions.GetSelectedData(query);

ddlPaperDate.DataTextField = "PaperStartDate";
ddlPaperDate.DataBind();
```

In CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),PaperStartDate,103), **103** is the format code. You can have a lot of format codes. Below is the link for the other format codes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should trim it in DB query

`string query = "select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PaperStartDate , 111) from HMDPaperManage ";`

Check this for other formats

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx