# The application result is datetime although SQL query have to return just Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date, datetime

Why the following datatable contains datetime although the expected result from my SQL query is Date ?

```
public static DataTable CheckCalcDateToSend(int month, int year, int camp)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss"].ToString()))
    {
        StringBuilder Query = new StringBuilder();
        Query.Append(" SELECT CONVERT(date, to_date) AS to_date FROM CalcAttend  ");
        Query.Append(" WHERE month = @month AND year = @year");
        Query.Append(" AND camp = @camp AND emp_num = 0 ORDER BY calc_date");


        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query.ToString(), con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = month;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = year;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camp", SqlDbType.Int).Value = camp;
            con.Open();
            using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt.Load(dataReader);
            }
        }

    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Dates in sql server still have a time value but the time is always exactly midnight.

Comment: @SeanLange : then what should i do to return just a date ? My dropdownlist source have to be just list of dates

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @SeanLange : I mean , I have a Drop Down List whose data source is that data table and have to be a date not a date time

Comment: Are you using an [`asp:DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? If so, you can set the `DataTextFormatString` property to format the date times to just output the dates.

Comment: Missing 1 rep for comments... have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4849412/5552144) post?

Comment: There is no Date datatype. It is System.DateTime, that is why it is getting converted into DateTime. You will have to remove the Time part before binding it to the dropdownlist.

Comment: Why not convert your datetime to varchar in select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net, "Date" type does not exist. Default is "DateTime" type. 
"Date" property in "DateTime" variable will give date component.
Alternatively, You can try to use DataTextFormatString for dropdownlist binding.

Refer this post [Date in dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146230/setting-date-format-in-dropdown-list)