# Convert dropdown values to DateTime after getting values from DataBase in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list that gets it's values from events on the database and it's working fine, this is the code that I'm using:

```
DataSet ds = event.ReturnFutureEvents();
meetingDropdown.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["date"].ToString();
meetingDropdown.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString();
meetingDropdown.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
meetingDropdown.DataBind();
```

However, this makes the values on the dropdown formated like 02/04/2020 00:00:00, and I want only the Date, without Time. The .ToString() on these doesn't accept any arguments, and converting the columns to DateTime doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DataTextFormatString`. In your case, you want something like this:

```
meetingDropdown.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
```

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring.

Comment: Didn't work for me, it just made all the values "dd/MM/yyyy", putting it after the DataBind has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17146490/2906166

Please check above answer.

```
  meetingDropdown.DataValueField =  ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString();
  meetingDropdown.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["date"].ToString();
  meetingDropdown.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
  meetingDropdown.DataBind();
```